# Unexpected drill hole behind voltage regulator in EAGLE

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am designing a PCB in EAGLE and I want to use an 7815 TO-220 voltage regulator. When I check the top or bottom layer mask of my PCB I can see that there is a hole (with no copper I think) behind the voltage regulator. Is this normal or I am using the wrong model?[image]

Comment: If the footprint is using an unplated hole for the TO-220 it might increase your manufacturing costs (if it's the only unplated hole). Looks like your mounting holes are also unplated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the spacing but that hole is likely there so you can screw the regulator to the board, or more likely mechanically attach a heatsink.

You can see an example:

[image]

If there was copper you'd run the risk of connecting the tab to a trace or an internal plane.  This wouldn't work so well if your internal layer contained a power plane.

You should be able to find a vertical part in Eagle if you prefer the voltage regulator to remain upright.

Answer (score 3):

That is the normal mounting hole for a TO-220 package when mounted "lying down" on the board.  If you are using a small heatsink, it would be placed between the regulator and board, and held in place, and in good contact with the regulator, by a screw through that hole.